# How do I add a variable for a Twig template in my preprocess function?

Tags: 8, theming

I'm using the following code to preprocess the variables for my template:

```
function template_preprocess_imagegallery_format(&$vars) {
  template_preprocess_image_formatter($vars);
  $vars['image']['#theme'] = 'igimage';
  $vars['image']['#thumbnail'] = ImageStyle::load('thumbnail')->buildUrl($vars ['image']['#uri']);
  $vars['image']['#fullimage'] = file_create_url($vars ['image']['#uri']);
}
```

The #uri variable is already present, and if I just modify it everything works fine. But I need to add additional variables here as I need two different styles of the same image. But simply adding those variables to the array doesn't work.

If I dump the available variables in my Twig template with `{{ dump(_context|keys) }}`, I don't see the variables I added there. If I try to use them in my template, nothing gets inserted.

I can see that the values are added to the array, when I dump the image variable in the theme that renders the entire field, I see my variables in the array. But they're still not available in the template that renders the image variable itself.

What else do I need to do to add a variable in my preprocess function that I can use in my Twig template?

Comment: You have a space between the array name `$vars` and your keys (e.g. `['image']`). I'm pretty sure that isn't allowed.

Comment: I removed the spaces, it doesn't actually matter and I have the same result with or without spaces. The spaces are from code I copied from an example.

Comment: Did you rename the function? It shouldn't be `template_preprocess_imagegallery_format` but 'template' should be replaced with your theme or module name. You will also need a cache clear.

Comment: Found a couple of good resources: [Twig best practices - preprocess functions and templates](https://www.drupal.org/node/1920746#render) and [Theme system overview](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/group/themeable/8).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally solved the problem, it turns out the problem was that I tried to add the variables in the wrong preprocessor. Editing the #theme works there, but to add variables I needed to preprocess the theme I set there:

```
function template_preprocess_imagegallery_format(&$vars) {
  template_preprocess_image_formatter($vars);
  $vars['image']['#theme'] = 'igimage';
}

function template_preprocess_igimage(&$vars) {
    $vars['thumbnail'] = ImageStyle::load('thumbnail')->buildUrl($vars['uri']);
    $vars['fullimage'] = file_create_url($vars['uri']);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For a theme whose machine name is *atvdirect*, create the *atvdirect.theme* file in the directory containing the *.info.yml* file for the theme, and add the following code.

```php
function atvdirect_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['logopath'] = '/'.drupal_get_path('theme','atvdirect') .'/logo.png';
}
```

Now you can use `{{ logopath }}` in the *page.html.twig* template file.